# Can a high entropy (heat death) dynamical system spontaneously arrive at a state of low entropy given enough time?

Tags: entropy

If you measure the entropy in a dynamical system which is at a maxima for entropy level (eg. heat death universe) why will it not revisit lower entropy states spontaneously?  That is, fluctuate away from a maxima?

Plot s on the y-axis, iteration/update/time on the x-axis.  Run the simulation forward for an arbitrarily long time.  Surely over long enough times, the level of entropy will decrease at times spontaneously.  Conversely, can we say heat death implies a flat line plot forever; no deviation from a maxima?

Why won't all possible state-space configurations be revisited in frequency proportion to their state-space probabilities?

Even if evolution towards a state of minimum entropy will require a passage through a permutation of exponentially unlikely lower energy states this is not a zero possibility.  Why will a heat death universe not spontaneously revisit a minima and re-birth?

I realise the numbers against the system spontaneously reaching a minima from a maxima are an immense exponential and we are trying to find them with a linear increase in iteration/update/time.  But why not?

Comment: Please provide an example of any natural spontaneous process of a system that results in an overall decrease in the entropy of the system plus its surroundings

Comment: PM 2Ring - you are the man!  Thank you!!  Great link - just the discussion I was looking for.  Great!